# Putty + Screen Auto Terminating Screens

Tags: gnu-screen, putty

I'm running screen inside a putty terminal. The problem I'm having is after a while of inactivity inside a screen, the screen automatically kills itself. So when I do things like run something overnight I'll come back in the morning to see that all my screens were terminated and I can't see the output (I know I can pipe it to a file but for these purposes I'd rather not). Is there any way I can stop this?

Thanks!

[edit]
Just to clarify, the putty terminal doesn't get disconnect. The problem happens even while I'm working in another screen. I'll be working in screen X and all of a sudden screen Y will disappear after it's been idle for a while.

Comment: Are you sure that your screens are terminating and they are not going to the background when you get disconnected?

Comment: Are you on someone else's shell server? It could be that they kill idle jobs after X amount of time

Comment: Does screen leave a message?  Or just "[screen is terminating]"?

Comment: It just leaves me "[screen is terminating]". And yea, I am on another computers shell. It could be that, I'll look into it.

Comment: yeah, this sounds like an idle process killer...

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like an idle-process killer.  By itself, if there was a network error or you were to close PuTTY, screen would just background itself, and you could recover by logging in again and doing 'screen -r'.  If that's not possible, then something must be killing your screen process(es).